Trouble using rust implementation of Autopilot - find_color
I am attempting to use the function find_color in the rust implementation of autopilot. Located in the bitmap module.
I have seen a working example here searching for a bitmap in another bitmap (find_bitmap) which has the same structure as find_color, and looks similar to what I have implemented it. But it's not working the way it should.
I want to search for the color black in a bitmap. Unless the first pixel is black it detects it, if black exists elsewhere in the image it isn't working, so it's like it is only searching 1 pixel only and not iterating over all the pixels in the image as it should be according to the description:
    /// Attempts to find `color` inside `rect` in `bmp` from the given
    /// `start_point`. Returns coordinates if found, or `None` if not. If
    /// `rect` is `None`, `bmp.bounds()` is used instead. If `start_point` is
    /// `None`, the origin of `rect` is used.
    ///
    /// Tolerance is defined as a float in the range from 0 to 1, where 0 is
    /// an exact match and 1 matches anything.

This is what I've tried:
extern crate autopilot;
extern crate image;
use autopilot::{bitmap::capture_screen_portion, geometry::{Point,Rect,Size}, key::type_string, mouse::{click, move_to, Button}, screen::get_color};
use std::time::Duration;
use std::{thread::sleep,thread};
use x_win::{get_active_window, XWinError};
use std::path::Path;
fn main() {
...................
           let rect_size = Size::new(7.0, 7.0);
           let start_point = Point::new(1.0, 0.0);
           let search_rect = Rect::new(start_point, rect_size);
           let tol = Some(0.3);
           let cf_point = Point::new(777 as f64, 415 as f64);
           let checkbox_folder = capture_screen_portion(Rect::new(
                        cf_point, 
                        rect_size,)).expect("Unable to capture screen portion");
           let checkbox_folder_path = Path::new(file ())
                   .parent()
                   .unwrap()
                   .parent()
                   .unwrap()
                   .join("..\\export_cf.png");
           checkbox_folder.image.save(&checkbox_folder_path).expect("Unable to save cropped screenshot");
           let test = checkbox_folder.find_color(black, tol, Some(search_rect), Some(start_point));
           println!("Test value: {:?}", test);
..................
}

I've also tried
let test = checkbox_folder.find_color(black, tol, None, None); and combinations there of.
However it shows none in the value I'm printing unless there is a black pixel at the start of the image.
The image that is getting captured and saved to ..\export_cf.png is a checkbox with a tick in it, and it confirms there is definitely black in the image that is being captured.
If I use find_every_color it doesn't find it either, get_color on a specific pixel however works, I just don't want to do it on 1 specific pixel if I can avoid it.
Can anyone help?
Added a sample image

EDIT - Updated the sample code to include cargo.toml and full main.rs that should be able to be built and run.
If you save the sample image above as sample.png and the open the test image and put it roughly in the centre of your screen and run the solution, it will capture an image and save it as export_test.png. You can see if it has captured it with black in it.
As long as black isn't at 0,0 then the test value will be none. Where as the sample image if loaded from disk it will search and find black correctly in the image. In this case the result will always be:

Black pixel found at: Some(Point { x: 3.0, y: 6.0 })



Cargo.toml

 [package]
 name = "test"
 version = "1.0.0"
 edition = "2021"
 
 [dependencies]
 autopilot = { git = "https://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopilot-rs" }
 image = "0.22.5"


main.rs

use autopilot::{
    bitmap::{capture_screen_portion,Bitmap},
    geometry::{Point, Rect, Size},
};
use image::GenericImageView;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    // Test with sample provided
    let img = image::open("sample.png").unwrap();
    let img_size = Size::new(img.width() as f64, img.height() as f64);

    let cf_point = Point::new(777 as f64, 415 as f64);
    let black = image::Rgba([0, 0, 0, 255]);
    let rect_size = Size::new(11.0, 11.0);
    let screen_rect_size = Size::new(100.0, 100.0);
    let start_point = Point::new(0.0, 0.0);
    let search_rect = Rect::new(start_point, rect_size);
    let tol = Some(0.3);

    // Test with screen capture at cf_point
    let checkbox_folder = capture_screen_portion(Rect::new(
        cf_point, 
        screen_rect_size,)).expect("Unable to capture screen portion");

    // Save screen capture to disk
    let checkbox_folder_path = Path::new(file!()).parent().unwrap().parent().unwrap().join("export_test.png");
    checkbox_folder.image.save(&checkbox_folder_path).expect("Unable to save cropped screenshot");

    // Search for black in screen capture
    let test = checkbox_folder.find_color(black, tol, Some(search_rect), None);

    println!("Test value: {:?}", test);

    // Search for black in sample image
    let bitmap = Bitmap {
        image: img,
        size: img_size,
        scale: 1f64,
    };

    let black_pos = bitmap.find_color(black, tol, Some(search_rect), Some(start_point));
    println!("Black pixel found at: {:?}", black_pos);
}


Can you add the definition of black as well as a sample image? For me this definitely works as expected.
One idea I have is that you might use an image with a wrong color format like Rgb<u8> or something like that instead of Rgba<u8>.

black is defined as let black = image::Rgba::<u8>([0, 0, 0, 255]); The image is created by capture_screen_portion. So it should be created correctly. If I capture part of the screen that is all black it returns a value, but if I capture a checkbox on screen with a black tick in it, it's not detecting black.

I just ran a test to capture a screenportion while cmd is open with a black background and the result is: Test value: Some(Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }).
If I run it against the checkbox image which definitely has black in it, it comes back with: Test value: None

@frankenapps I've uploaded a sample image as well

I still can not reproduce your problem. Can you try again with the sample image you provided and the code from the linked gist? When I run the code I get: Some(Point { x: 3.0, y: 6.0 }) just like expected.

In case it is easier to test here is a standalone, slightly modified (for educational purposes) version of the aforementioned gist that also correctly outputs Some(Point { x: 11.0, y: 13.0 }) when executed.

@frankenapps sorry just pinging a comment in for you - wasn't sure you had seen my post

Your code snippet is useless. I do not know how your screenshot looks, neither can I reproduce it. So I can't help with that. You need to build a stripped down version of your sample that only uses the image that you provided. See MRE.

@frankenapps ummm I've added cargo.toml, main.rs and a test image you can open and should be able to use to capture a screenshot that has black in it other than the first pixel
